# How do I define a CONSTANT value as a function so its domain is model values, not strings?

Tags: tla+

Consider the case where I have a set of nodes, and I want to declare some ordering over them. The easiest way to do this is to declare both the set of nodes and their ranking as constants:

```
CONSTANTS Node, NodeRank
ASSUME NodeRank \in [Node -> Nat]
ASSUME \A n, m \in Node : NodeRank[n] = NodeRank[m] <=> n = m
```

Now it comes time to assign model values to these constants. `Node` is easy enough, I just define it as a set of model values in the toolbox:

```
Node <- [ model value ] {n1, n2}
```

I try to do something similar with `NodeRank` with ordinary assignment:

```
NodeRank <- [n1 |-> 1, n2 |-> 2]
```

However, when I run TLC the `ASSUME` statements are violated. Further examination reveals this is because in the ordinary assignment of `NodeRank`, `n1` and `n2` are treated as strings instead of model values. This makes sense, because that is the usual method of defining records (which use strings as their domain). How do I define `NodeRank` such that it uses the `n1` and `n2` model values as its domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extend `TLC`, you can write this as `n1 :> 1 @@ n2 :> 2`.